# How to display the array values in table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have array of contents which is getting the data from the dictionary values, now i need to display array contents in table view cell, but it was not showing proper data.

Here is the source code

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.illArray count]; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *lDict = [self.illArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *lTitle = [lDict objectForKey:@"title"];
        if ([lTitle rangeOfString:@"Symptoms"].length > 0)
        {
            [m_cIllResultArray addObject:lDict];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < [m_cIllResultArray count]; i++)
    {
        sDict = [m_cIllResultArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *sDetail = [sDict objectForKey:@"SYMPTOMS"];
        [sDict setValue:sDetail forKey:@"details"];

    }
```

NSLog(@"ARRAY VALUES1:-%@", [sDict valueForKey:@"details"]);

The data format is:

```
ARRAY VALUES : (
        {
        SYMPTOMS =         (
            "Abdominal pain",
            Constipation,
            Diarrhea,
            "Hard to breathe"
        );
        independentItem = 0;
        module = 117;
        seqCounter = 101;
        sequence = 10010;
        session = 101;
        title = "Low Alert: Symptoms";
    },
        {
        SYMPTOMS =         (
            "Abdominal pain",
            Constipation,
            Diarrhea
        );
        independentItem = 0;
        module = 117;
        seqCounter = 102;
        sequence = 10022;
        session = 101;
        title = "High Alert : Symptoms";
    },
        {
        SYMPTOMS =         (
            "Abdominal pain",
            Dehydration,
            "Elevated temperature (>100 degrees)"
        );
        independentItem = 0;
        module = 117;
        seqCounter = 101;
        sequence = 10040;
        session = 101;
        title = "Low Alert: Symptoms";
    }
```

i need to display symptoms key inside contents in table view

Thanks in advance

Comment: See its look like [ click this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332507/numberofsectionintablesview-numberofrowsinsection/10333919#10333919) and it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

make a custom tableview cell and put all the data in that. read these tutorial for more details

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/

http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder

Answer (score 0):

make custom tableview for example flicker cell or any other you can use and if possible make plist and transfer data and you can reuse its better i have got result from this way if you find any query in this way tell me i will send you demo code.....hope you will got your solution this way

Answer (score 0):

Try this..i think it works..

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.illArray count]; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *lDict = [self.illArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *lTitle = [lDict objectForKey:@"title"];
        if ([lTitle rangeOfString:@"Symptoms"].length > 0)
        {
            [m_cIllResultArray addObject:[sDict objectForKey:@"SYMPTOMS"]];
        }
    }
NSLog(@"ARRAY VALUES1:-%@", m_cIllResultArray);
```